# How read a row of richbox and than assign this row as a string

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to that, my app read a row of richbox and than assign this row as a string value. How can i programme this ability for windows app in c# in visual studio.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far!

Comment: Use the Lines property of the RTB! (Note that you can read them but not change them)

Answer (score -1):

Use string method IndexOf to detect a new line char in the string (\n) and then use method SubString to pick out the desired part of the string.